# MS Graph - get all users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to pull back a list of all users, my expected result would be approximately 20,000 users.

Graph appears to limit me to 1000.

The graph call
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`
returns 100, if I add $top to it I can get up to 999.
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$top=999`
The $top filter works as long as the value is < 1000.
Has anyone found a way or know of a way to get > 1000 users back in a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the results are paged. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging):

> Some queries against Microsoft Graph return multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the `$top` query parameter to specifically limit the page size in a request. When a result set spans multiple pages, Microsoft Graph returns an `@odata.nextLink` property in the response that contains a URL to the next page of results.

You need to follow the `@odata.nextLink` URI until you reach the final page (which is simply a page without an `@odata.nextLink` value).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make multiple API calls incrementing the $skip parameter with each call.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skip-parameter

Comment: The documentation explicitly says "$skip isn't supported." for users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http